# using async/await in mongoose schema subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, schema

I have been trying to get an ID from TransactionType Schema and use it as a reference in the new Category but it always calls to create the new category before it finishes the query of new TransactionType.

```
const Category = require("../models/categories.model");
const TransactionType = require("../models/transactiontype.model");
async function saveNewCategory(req, res, next) {
    let transactionID;
    const transID = await TransactionType.findOne({ name: req.body.transactionType })
        .populate("transactionType")
        .exec((error, res) => {
            console.log(res.id);
            transactionID = res.id;
            console.log(transactionID);
            return transactionID;
        });

    const newCategory = await new Category({
        name: req.body.name,
        transactionType: transactionID || transID ,
        image: req.body.image,
        description: req.body.description
    });
    try {
        await newCategory.save();
        await res
            .status(200)
            .send({ response: "Response " + JSON.stringify(req.body, undefined, 2) });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
module.exports = {
    saveNewCategory
};
```

It creates newCategory with transactionType undefined before it finishes transID.
Please find below the Schema for Category.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const category = new Schema({
    name: String,
    transactionType : {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "TransactionType"
    },
    image: String,
    description: String
});

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', category);
module.exports = Category;
```

Find below the TransactionType model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const transactionType = new Schema({
    transaction: String
});
const TransactionType = mongoose.model('TransactionType', transactionType);
module.exports = TransactionType;
```

I will be grateful if anyone could assist me with understanding this. I have gone through many books and blogs to understand async await but still no answer.

Comment: `const transID = await TransactionType.findOne({ name: req.body.transactionType }) .populate("transactionType")` That's already a promise and you don't need the `exec()` and callback. Also really would be best to be inside the try. And the `new Category()` is not actually async, so you don't need to `await` it. Make the change to the first method, remove the await on the `new Category()` and then move all that code inside the `try` block at the top of it. Job done.

Comment: Wow.. It hit the nail right on the head... Thank you @NeilLunn... Perfect job...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can put everything whats async in an immediate async function. This way the `saveNewCategory` won`t end before your async opereations finish.

```
async function saveNewCategory(req, res, next) {
    (async () => {
      await asyncStuff()
    })()
}
```

Edit: to understand better async await and promises check this article out:
https://pouchdb.com/2015/03/05/taming-the-async-beast-with-es7.html